# Displaying multiple columns using VLOOKUP in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vlookup

Lets say in a worksheet, lets call this SHEET_2, I have student information.

[image: Sheet2]

On another sheet, lets call this SHEET_1, I want to be able to lookup a students ID number and have all the students marks from assignments, tests, etc to be displayed.

Lets say there are 5 different marks per student. On sheet1, I type in the students ID number, and on row 2 I want the mark of assignment 1 to be displayed, and the row below, row 3, I want the mark of assignment 2 to be displayed.  How would I go about this using a single formula?

Currently I have 
=VLOOKUP(StudentID,Sheet_2,2,FALSE) to display assignment one

=VLOOKUP(StudentID,Sheet_2,3,FALSE) to display assignment two on the row below.

How could I combine this into a single formula where I don't have to have a separate col_index_num for each row?

Comment: Perhaps you could use `ROW()` instead of a number for the `col_index_num`?

Comment: How is the data structured on sheet 2?

Comment: @fixer1234 column A has the student ID,  Column B has the Students name, Columns C-H has grades of the students. I'll post an image later on if needed.

Comment: @fixer1234 I included an image of sheet 2

Comment: Thanks for the replies,  I think using ROW gave me my desired result

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

```
=TRANSPOSE(VLOOKUP(StudentID,Sheet_2,{3,4},FALSE))
```

(Column 2 would return the student's name, not Assignment 1's result.)

The trick to it is using the array constant `{3,4}` for the fields to return. It gives you both of them in a single formula.

`TRANSPOSE()` then takes the row form those results are given to you in and makes them a column of returns so that they fall in rows 2 and 3 for you (so presumably your entry in row 1, then these).

Of course, several other ways to do it as well, but this seems about the simplest.